# Javascript issue: Script that checks to see if words were included in an input box. Whole words only

Tags: javascript

I have an input box and that's working great, but my issue is with the script that checks to see if certain words were included in it. Right now I have:

```
$gameVariables.value(1).toLowerCase().includes("steal") || $gameVariables.value(1).toLowerCase().includes("thief") || $gameVariables.value(1).toLowerCase().includes("pickpocket")
```

This is working fine except I would prefer it to work for whole words only. How would I go about doing that?

I was also wondering if there's a way to shorten this script so I don't have to copy and paste to same line for every word. I've tried the following code (which doesn't work. It only works for the first word but not the ones that come after.):

```
$gameVariables.value(1).toLowerCase().includes("steal","thief","pickpocket")
```

Comment: `$gameVariables.value(1).toLowerCase()` is a string, correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe so! ^_^

Comment: I believe you can also do is use regex like below
`/^(thief|steal|pickpocket)$/i`.test($gameVariables.value(1)). In this case you won't need to use lower case either, and they will only check true if it is only thief or steal or pickpocket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the words which exactly matches either `theif` or `steal` or `pickpocket` you can use the following code

```
    const value = $gameVariables.value(1);
    const regex = /^(thief|steal|pickpocket)$/i;
    return regex.test(value);
```

So to explain the regex above,

- `^` will make sure that the regex matches from the start
- `(` and `)` creates a group for which regex should match
- `|` is like or operator in coding
- `$` is used when you want the end to exactly match with the end of the regex
- `i` basically is a flag to tell that you ignore the case while doing the check. So you won't need to use the `.toLowerCase()` either here

So the code above would basically check if the word is exactly matching either `theif` or `steal` or `pickpocket` and would return `false` if the word is `theifs` or `theif steal`

But if you don't want the exact match and only want to know if the input value contains these words then the simple answer would be to not use `^` and `$`

```
    const value = $gameVariables.value(1);
    const regex = /(thief|steal|pickpocket)/i;
    return regex.test(value);
```

And the result would be that it would be true for exact matches like `thief`, `steal` and `pickpocket` and it would also be true when either of the word is present in the whole statement like `this statement contains thief`. The second method would fail for words like `the` or `stl`. But the problem is that it would also match with `steals` or would return true for statements like `this statement contains steals`. To fix it you can use the following code

```
    const value = $gameVariables.value(1);
    const regex = /(thief|steal|pickpocket)\b/i;
    return regex.test(value);
```

- `\b` allows you to perform a “whole words only” search

thus, it would return false if the statement contains `this statement contains steals` but would return true when the statement contains `this statement contains steal` or word which exactly matches `steal`

Comment: Thank you very much! for your detailed answer! This has (almost) solved my problems! One more thing I would like to ask is, about the ^ and $. This is great for making it match the whole word only. However, is there a way to still recognize the whole word is there, even when a sentence has been typed and the whole word is in the middle of that sentence? Hope I'm making sense!

Comment: @Shadow I updated my answer for the whole word search in the statement

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array (`[]`) of words to look for and then do this:

```js
// Your list of words to look for
const words = ["steal", "thief", "pickpocket", "quick"];

// Your string
const str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

const result = words.some(w => str.includes(w));
console.log(result);
```

[`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will return `true` if any of the words are found in your string.